# Get post title with link

Tags: permalinks, get-the-title

I am using this code to send an email from my wordpress site. It send permalinks of the posts. How can i edit this to have linked titles instead of just permalinks;

```
if(count($ids) > 0){
                $user_id = $usermeta['user_id'];
                $userdata = get_userdata($user_id);
                $email = $userdata->data->user_email;
                //echo $email;
                $links = '';
                foreach($ids as $id){
                    $link = get_permalink($id);
                    $links .= $link . ' <br>';
                }
                //echo $links;

                if (have_posts()) : 
                    while (have_posts()) : 
                        the_post();
                        $emailTpl = get_the_content();
                    endwhile;
                endif;

                $message = preg_replace('/\[\%urls\%\]/', $links, $emailTpl);
                $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: text/html;"; 
                //wp_mail('ehmudroy@gmail.com', 'New project notification', $link);
                //wp_mail('lijb@stunningtech.com', 'New project notification', $message, $headers);
                wp_mail($email, 'New project notification', $message, $headers);
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you use it like that??

```
<a href="<?php get_permalink($id); ?>"><?php the_title($id); ?></a>
```

for use to that

```
foreach($ids as $id){
  $link = get_permalink($id);
  $title = get_the_title($id);
  $links .= '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$title.'</a>'.'<br/>' ;
  //$links .= $link . ' <br>';
}
```

[get_permalink](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

[get_the_title](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)

Try to use that while I'm coding your code.

Comment: Did you have a chance?

Comment: @Ahmad Good man. Have a good day. :-) :-D :-)